Configuring Apache 2.4 on Windows for HTTPS with a passphrase-protected key file
As per the title, I'm trying to configure Apache 2.4 on a Windows server (Win 2022) to support HTTPS connections.  The CA signing service I'm using provided me a CRT and KEY file in PEM (Base64) format, where the private key file is encrypted with a passphrase.  I've reviewed the Apache docs and I understand that:

I need to properly configure SSLPassPhraseDialog
I can't use the default builtin option as it's not compatible with Windows
The exec: and ! (pipe) options mention no compatibility issues and presumably should work

Since I have Python on the server (it's hosting a Django app), I assumed the simplest option would be a single-line Python script with a print('my_passphrase') statement to write the passphrase to stdout.  But when I try that, I'm getting an error trying to start the server:
AH02580: Init: Pass phrase incorrect for key
With some further troubleshooting, I've confirmed the problem is, my Python script never runs.  Apache does find the file (I confirmed this by renaming it, and seeing a different error), but it never actually executes it.
So I'm needing some guidance on either (1) how to get the Python to run, or (2) some alternative means of providing the passphrase which doesn't need Python.
PLEASE, ONE VERY IMPORTANT PROVISO:  After googling for help, I've seen over & over the way people tend to deal with this is to use OpenSSL to remove the passphrase from the key file. I already know how to do this, and I've confirmed it works.  But I'm looking for a better alternative.
That said, here's the particulars of what I've put in my httpd-ssl.conf file:
SSLPassPhraseDialog  "exec:D:/the/path/to/passphrase.py"
SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/ssl/my.certificate.file.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/ssl/my.key.file.with.passphrase.key"

Then passphrase.py contains:
print('my_passphrase')
with open('D:\\the\\path\\to\\passphrase.out.txt','w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('it ran')

And again:

If I run passphrase.py in the console, it does the print and generates the output file
If I rename passphrase.py to some other file name, Apache throws a different error, saying it couldn't find the file.
If I change SSLCertificateKeyFile to point instead to the non-passphrase-protected file, my.key.file.without.passphrase.key, Apache launches normally.
But if I keep the protected key file, and give the correct Python file name, Apache generates the "Pass phrase incorrect for key" error -- and no output file gets created by the Python script -- indicating that the script never ran.


Why is it better to not remove the passphrase from the key? If you want to automate the startup (as you do) you need to store it in some file and you have a documentation on your system where that passphase can be found (your configuration files). So any attacker can find it anyway. So what is the point in this?

Let's say it goes back to a complicated and painful trauma from my early childhood involving a gambling ring and a TRS-80 computer, and I'm not comfortable sharing it online with a bunch of strangers. None of that is true of course, but I'm just trying to determine whether there IS some other solution than removing the passphrase. If you don't have an answer to the question, no need to respond. But of course, if you know for a fact there IS no other option, then by all means respond and explain why the passphrase makes the file unusable for this use case. That would be valuable info to share.

I did not send an answer, I raised a question to motivate you to think about what you are trying to do. If you decide to continue your quest, sure, perfectly fine. I do not have an answer to the question which is why I did not write an answer, but a comment. I do not have an answer since I am not familiar with MS-Windows systems. There are solutions for standard Linux systems that are the usual base for such task. But MS-Windows is different from the standard in many aspects. Sorry. Good luck! You will certainly learn a lot which is a good thing!

Understood. To provide a less flippant response, in my experience (I'm a test engineer), I've seen too many instances where a developer "took the easy way out" of a thorny problem by removing the feature or component, then inventing a rationale why it was never needed in the first place. Finding so many other articles where the solution was to delete the passphrase, left me suspicous... is that really a "solution?" Or just an easy out?

Sure, I experienced such situations too. But on the other hand I saw quite a lot of test engineers insist on paradigms or rules just because they existed, without ever challenging them ... Meaning: what is "a solution" in your current situation? The sense of a passphrase is to protect the key. That works, but requires you to provide that passphrase each time the key is used. It is actually you who is trying to break with that measure by trying to automate that. An attempt that shatters the desired protecting since any attacker can easily access that passphrase then...

Trying to be careful about turning this into an extended dialog :) but your point brings up a question.  A common practice with any Django project is to have a file, ".env", which contains deployment-specific variables and particularly the SECRET_KEY value for the application. The point being to protect that data from discovery by hackers. So are you saying the security provided by a .env file is a myth?

Depends on where that file is, right? I assume you are talking about a container based approach. In that case the file most likely is used to create environment variables for the runtime. If that service is compromised then is possible to access those values for the attacker. But at least those secrets are not part of the source file tree, so are not accessible in the repository. They somehow to have to be made available for the tool chain though that deploys the solution. Somewhere those secrets have to be present and are accessible. Which is different to manually entering them.
